# Scala: case class defaults values and equals/hashCode: Point ≠ Point(0,0)

Tags: scala

why are these sets are all different?

```
case class Point(x:Int = 0, y:Int = 0)

Set(Point, Point)               // Set(Point)
Set(Point, Point(0,0))          // Set(Point, Point(0,0))
Set(Point(0,0), Point(x=0,y=0)) // Set(Point(0,0), Point(0,0))
```

set equality is false too.

i would think that even with defaults, equals and hashCode would depend on the values, not on the string or something.

Answer (score 1):

silly me, scala has type inference

```
Set(Point)             : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Point.type]
Set(Point, Point(0,0)) : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Serializable]
Set(Point(0,0))        : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Point]
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand how this is relevant to your question. The root of the problem, as Yury correctly mentioned in an earlier post (I wonder why he deleted it) is that `Point` is the companion object. What you probably meant is `Point()`, which is indeed equal to `Point(0,0)`. Or did you just means that the inferred type od the sets allowed you to realize that `Point` referes to the companion object?

Comment: I also wish @Yury 's answer were undeleted.

Comment: (right, i was aware of type versus instance). my point is that if this were java, you'd either need to say `Set<Object>` or it would fail on `Set<Point>`. Scala infers the most general type (or something like that). it was late and i had thought the no-args could be a constructor (i guess like you can sometimes drop the parens from a zero-arity method).